# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: USA

Tags: python, sqlite

I am moving data from one database to another with the following statment

```
    cursor.execute("\
                INSERT INTO table (ID, Country)\
                SELECT ID, Country\
                FROM database.t\
                WHERE Country = `USA`\
                GROUP BY Country\
                ;")
```

But I get the error

```
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: USA
```

Can't figure out why

Comment: Use _single quotes_ around `USA`, rather than backticks.

Comment: `WHERE country = 'USA'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm a moron thanks, please post your comment as an answer so I can check mark it and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes, not backticks, when referring to a string literal in your SQLite query:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, Country)
SELECT ID, Country
FROM database.t
WHERE Country = 'USA'
GROUP BY Country
```